# PhpStorm sftp deploy with SSH Proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, phpstorm

I'm trying to deploy some code with PHPStorm using sftp. I need to use an ssh proxy to do so. Now in the terminal this is no problem: I add a few lines in the .ssh/config file (Namely: ProxyCommand ssh [...]) and everything works fine. But PHPStorm seems to ignore any configurations in the .ssh/config file.

The question: Is it possible in PHPStorm to configure an SSH-Proxy or can I tell PHPStorm to use the .ssh/config file like any other program that uses ssh?

Best regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deployment through proxy (be it ordinary FTP or SFTP) is not currently supported.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-14953 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress (for SFTP).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If IntelliJ would just use my .ssh/config I would be happy.

Comment: IDE uses some Java based library for all SFTP/SSH communications (I guess this one: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/ -- based on https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Third-Party+Software+Used+by+PhpStorm )

Answer (score 4):

I managed to connect to target server through middle server using PhpStorm by issuing following command through commandline

ssh -L 2222:target-server.com:22 middleserver.com

and using following settings in PhpStorm

and in PhpStorm 
host: localhost
port: 2222
username/password as required for target server

Comment: Thanks [@adax2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398140/adax2000), this works.

Answer (score 3):

@LazyOne is right, IDE does not using native ssh, which lead to ssh proxy does not work。

example：

after set up the proxy tunnel

shell code:

```
ssh -f -N -L 2203:host_ip_c:22 username@host_ip_b -p host_ip_b_port
```

I would be able setup direct ssh to host_ip_c by

shell code

```
ssh localhost -p 2203
```

but it did not work by IDE

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make this work on PhpStorm 2018.1.2 by a combination of ProxyCommand and ssh tunneling.

I set up my .ssh/config like this:

```
Host jumpserver
    HostName jumpserver.example.com
    User user

Host 10.0.0.*
    ProxyCommand ssh jumpserver -W %h:%p
```

And then opened a tunnel using the following command

```
ssh 10.0.0.15 -L 2000:localhost:22 -N
```

Lastly enter localhost and port 2000 into your PhpStorm config settings

[image: phpstorm sftp settings]

Comment: It works for me, thanks! BTW, you can replace `ProxyCommand ssh jumpserver -W %h:%p` with `ProxyJump jumpserver` if your openssh version is the newest, see `man ssh_config`.